# Iphone: Converting a UIImage to RGB888 and Back again

Tags: iphone, image-processing, uiimage, rgb

I have a requirement to convert a image to RGB888 so some effects can be performed on it, once it is done, I will receive the modified image, and I will then need to convert it from the RGB888 back to a UIImage for display.

Does anyone know if any good libraries I could look into or point me in a good direction?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to render your image into a `CGBitmapContext` if you want access to the individual pixels in a particular colorspace. Apple has a [Technical Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2007/qa1509.html) about this very topic. To use it on iOS, you'll need to use the [`CGImage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImage/CGImage) property of your `UIImage`. Remember that manipulating large images is very processor- and memory-intensive.